How is event count per user calculated in Google Analytics
Google Analytics has the events dashboard under "Examine User Behavior", which displays (event name, event count, total users, event count per user). Event count per user is described as average number of events per user. Using BigQuery, I'm able to tie exactly to event count & total users. However, the event count per user ties on some of the event names, but not the others (page view for example). Is there an additional calculation that happens for particular event names to get the event count per user metric, that is not simply (event count/total users)?
WITH test AS(SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.googleanalyticsevents` where dataset = 'analytics_xxx' 
and cast(concat(left(event_date,4),'-',substr(event_date,(-4),2),'-',right(event_date,2)) as date) between '2024-03-28' and '2024-03-29'),
test2 as (
SELECT
cast(concat(left(event_date,4),'-',substr(event_date,(-4),2),'-',right(event_date,2)) as date) dt,
event_name,
count(DISTINCT user_pseudo_id) usercount,
count(*) eventcount
FROM test
GROUP BY cast(concat(left(event_date,4),'-',substr(event_date,(-4),2),'-',right(event_date,2)) as date) , event_name

ORDER BY 1,2
)

SELECT dt, event_name, eventcount, usercount, (eventcount/usercount)
FROM test2



Your logic and formula are correct. However, it is possible to write a simpler query without using so many string functions. The discrepancy between the results is not a significant issue because GA4 uses HLL+ 14 to count distinct users, which is not as accurate as BigQuery. To learn more about the differences between GA4 and BQ data, you can refer to this URL https://developers.google.com/analytics/blog/2023/bigquery-vs-ui.
